# Trigonometric integral with square root (residue theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

I can't solve this integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+\cos^2x}\,dx$$
I've tried with the definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$ as complex exponential functions but the square root stands in the way! I want to use the residue Theorem but it's difficult to figure out the singularities of this function.

Comment: The substitution $t=\sqrt{\tan{x}}$ helps, but the answer is very ugly.

Comment: I've tried but I obtain: integral of (t^(1/2))/(t^2+1+sqrt(1+t^2)) dt, with t=0 to 1, wich to me it's still problematic to solve

Comment: @Gitana I think the suggestion of Sonnhard is smart and the resulting integral I am sure is done somewhere else on MSE. The integral is improper (and convergent) but that is no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write your integral in the form
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}\sec^2(x)}{\sec^2(x)+1}dx$$
then Substitute
$$u=\tan(x)$$ and we get $$du=\sec^2(x)dx$$ and our integral has the form
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{u^2+2}du$$ now Substitute
$$s=\sqrt{u}$$ with $$ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du$$
can you finish?
and you will Need that $$a^4+b^4=(a^2+b^2-\sqrt{2}ab)(a^2+b^2+\sqrt{2}ab)$$
and $$2\int\frac{s^2}{s^4+2}ds=\frac{\log \left(\sqrt{2} s^2-2 \sqrt[4]{2}
   s+2\right)-\log \left(\sqrt{2} s^2+2 \sqrt[4]{2}
   s+2\right)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt[4]{2}
   s\right)+2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}
   s+1\right)}{2\ 2^{3/4}}$$

Comment: You would need the factoring formula $a^4+b^4$ and the following partial fraction decomposition is cumbersome, but doable and I am sure it has been done on MSE before. The top-bottom multiplication of $sec^2x$ is smart...+1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After your first substitution I did it differently applying the residue theorem in the end to the integral in u : integral of sqrt(u)/(u^2+2) du , with u= 0 to inf. I integrated it on a path chosen in order to take advantage of the branch cut of the square root on the negative real axis.

Comment: The result of the computation is correct and the moltiplication for sec^2x very useful.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually no need for a primitive of $\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+\cos^2 x}$ in order to compute the given integral, since

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+\cos^2 x}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto \arctan u}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2+u^2}\,du\stackrel{u\mapsto v^2}{=}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{v^2}{v^4+2}\,dv$$
and the RHS equals
$$2^{-1/4}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{z^2}{z^4+1}=2^{3/4}\pi i\left[\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\zeta_8}\frac{z^2}{z^4+1}+\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\zeta_8^3}\frac{z^2}{z^4+1}\right]$$
where $\zeta_8=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$, or, by De l'Hopital rule,
$$ 2^{3/4}\pi i\left[\left.\frac{2z^2}{4z^3}\right|_{z=\zeta_8}+\left.\frac{2z^2}{4z^3}\right|_{z=\zeta_8^3}\right]=2^{-1/4}\pi i\left[\frac{1}{\zeta_8}+\frac{1}{\zeta_8^3}\right]=2^{-1/4}\pi i\left[\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{i^3}\right]=\color{red}{\pi 2^{-3/4}}.$$

Comment: I did it in the same way but without the substitution in v, so I had to choose a "keyhole" path with branch cut in the positive real axis. I checked the result on wolfram alpha and it's correct.